# Integration by Partial Frac.

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions

Where do I go on this integration by partial fractions problem?

[image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkEjN.jpg

Comment: Would any of the answerers please take the opportunity to edit the question using mathjax?  You each must have had to time and wherewithal to click on the link, perhaps open to a new tab, going back and forth from image to your answer, or you copied the link onto paper, then answered.  The very least one of you answerers could have done was to insert the image directly into the post! As you can see, at least with the image inserted, your answers may make more sense to others stopping by. You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

We have

$f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x^4-2x^2-8}=$

$\frac{x^2}{(x-2)(x+2)(x^2+2)}=$

$\frac{a}{x-2}+\frac{b}{x+2}+\frac{cx+d}{x^2+2}$

this gives

$a=\frac{1}{6}$

obtained by multiplying by $(x-2)$ and replacing $x$ by $2$.

$b=\frac{-1}{6}$

obtained by multiplying by $(x+2)$ and replacing $x$ by $-2$.

$c=-a-b=0$

obtained by multiplying by $x$ and
 $x\to \infty$

and

$d=a-b=\frac{1}{3}$

obtained by replacing $x$ by $0$.

thus

$f(x)=\frac{1}{6}(\frac{1}{x-2}-\frac{1}{x
+2}+\frac{1}{1+(\frac{x}{2})^2})$

and the primitive

$F(x)=\frac{1}{6}(ln( |\frac{x-2}{x+2}|$

$+2arctan(\frac{x}{2}  ))+C$

defined in $(-\infty,-2) $ or $(-3,2)$ or $(2,+\infty)$.

Comment: My comment was referring to editing the OP's post: It's good for you have to inclused it in your answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can either substitue values in for $x$ like $2$ that cancel out other terms or you can actually foil it all out and then set set up a system of equations with the coefficients of terms of equal degree. For instance, if $x^2+2x=Ax^2+Ax+Bx$, you would have $Ax^2=x^2\implies A=1$ and $Ax+Bx=2x\implies A+B=2$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Put $x^2=y$  to get $$\dfrac y{y^2-2y-8}=\dfrac y{(y-4)(y+2)}=\dfrac A{y-4}+\dfrac B{y+2}$$

Comment: how do replace $dx$.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam, Once Partial Fraction is done, return to $x$

Comment: Abdallah, if $y=x^2$, then $dy = 2x\,dx$

Comment: @amWhy, Do we really need to replace $dx$?

Comment: The OP did fine with respect to setting up the partial fractions, if you took the time to read and translated what was written in the OP's linked message.  S/he said explicitly that s/he was asking how to continue from where s/he left off...No need to have reformulated the problem.